# Qt: QTabWidget causes unnecessary repaints

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have found that `QTabWidget` exhibits a really strange behaviour when it comes to repainting its children. The following code is the minimal example that I created to observe this problem.

Suppose I have a custom widget (a drawing) that has costly paint event hadler. So I need to minimize the number of times it is repainted. But the problem is that if this drawing widget is inside QTabWidget it receives many unnecesary repaint requests as a response to changes in some other totally unrelated widgets (in the example below - the button and label).

At the end of the example you can change variable `withTabWidget`. If it is set to `True`, the drawing is repainted (i.e. the number in the drawing is increased) every time the button is pressed. If it is set to `False`, the drawing is not repainted (the number in the drawing stays the same) when the button is pressed, which is the correct behaviour I need. But obviously, I also need to use the tab widget in my app layout...

Any idea how to make the tab widget work correctly, without unnecessary repaints?

Note: Qt 4.8.4 (tested on both 32 and 64-bits), PySide 1.2.1., Windows 7

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui


class MyDrawing(QtGui.QLabel):
    # drawing is a widget which has user defined paint event handler
    # the painting can be costly so we must avoid unnecessary repainting

    repaintCount = 0

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        # a very simple example which count ...
        # the number of times the paintEvent was executed
        self.repaintCount += 1
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawText(10, 10, str(self.repaintCount))


class MyContainer(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyContainer, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        # there is a button ...
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Press me.")
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.pressed.connect(self.onButtonPressed)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        # .. and a label ...
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # ... and a drawing
        self.drawing = MyDrawing()
        layout.addWidget(self.drawing)

    def onButtonPressed(self):
        # pressing button only changes the label
        # it does not change the drawing 
        # so drawing should not be repainted
        # but when the container is inside QTabWidget it IS repainted
        self.label.setText(str(self.button.isChecked()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = QtGui.QMainWindow()

    # change this True/False!!!
    withTabWidget = True
    # True = problem: MyDrawing IS repainted when button1 is pressed
    # False = OK: MyDrawing IS NOT repainted when button1 is pressed
    if withTabWidget:
        tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget()
        tabWidget.addTab(MyContainer(), "Tab1")
        form.setCentralWidget(tabWidget)
    else:
        form.setCentralWidget(MyContainer())

    form.show()
    result = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(result)
```

Update: By tracking the events on QTabWidget, I discovered, that when the label is changed, some animation object is inserted (child is added) into the QTabWidget. And the QTabWidget responds by repainting the whole area it covers. This is different with other widget types, when the animation object is inserted, it does not repaint its whole area. Unfortunately I still have no workaround to solve it. Maybe will have make my own TabWidget which I would like to avoid at all costs.

Update2: another interesting aspect is that when I start the example application above with the QTabWidget, the number which is drawn in the drawing is 2. When I start it without QTabWidget, the number is 1. So it is another example of unnecessary repainting.

Comment: You might want to try QStackedWidget instead. I have no idea if it will be better than QTabWidget.

Comment: I have just tested QStackedWidget and it does not suffer from this problem. Seems I will have to make my own TabWidget from QTabBar and QStackedWidget.

Comment: @V.K. Consider submiting a bug for Qt, at least there is a chance that this issue will be clarified by Qt team.

Comment: Submitted a bug to qt-project. https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-38741

Comment: After two and half years, I can still confirm with the newest PyQt5 that the described issue is still present. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-38741